# How can I create a "switch to Chrome" Keyboard Shortcut in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint

I'm trying to setup a few keyboard shortcuts that will let me `ALT+TAB` in to specific applications.  I know I can use the command `wmctrl -a "- Google Chrome"` to do the actual switching, but I'm having trouble wiring it up to a keyboard shortcut.

The obvious option would be the "Command" section of the CompizConfig Settings ... only that doesn't work.  No matter what keyboard shortcut I set, when I press it nothing happens (it doesn't invoke the specified command).

So, I'm either looking for:

A) an alternate way to specify a global keyboard shortcut (In Linux Mint MATE)

B) a way to debug/fix my CompizConfig Settings so that my Commands actually work.

Any help with either would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MATE:

1. Go to: Menu > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts
2. Click Add (at the bottom of the window)
3. Enter a name (like "Switch to Chrome")
4. Enter the command exactly like you had it (wmctrl -a "- Google Chrome")
5. Click Apply
6. Click the "Disabled" text to the right of the newly created custom shortcut
7. Enter the desired keyboard shortcut

In Cinnamon:

1. Go to: Menu > Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts
2. Click Add custom shortcut (at the bottom of the window)
3. Enter a name (like "Switch to Chrome")
4. Enter the command exactly like you had it (wmctrl -a "- Google Chrome")
5. Click Add
6. Double-click one of the unassigned keyboard bindings
7. Enter the keyboard shortcut

Comment: Perfect, except under MATE you can find "Keyboard Shortcuts" under `Menu > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`.  From there (ie. from step #2 above onward) everything works great.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I updated the post to include both MATE and Cinnamon instructions.